# FormView with Jquery.ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, formview

I have a requirement to fill the FormView, DataLIst using jquery.ajax
I have 2 ways to do it

**1)** When I do not receive any data in jquery.ajax but this leads to an error because when the focus reaches to the line -- GridView1.DataSource = ds;
This shows an error "Object Reference not set to an instance of object"
I have checked in debug mode data set object ds is fill with data.
Error occurs only when this assigns to DataSource

**2)** And 2nd option is if i receive the data set data in terms of arraylist or array then how will i populate my Formview.
Because I'm using **<%#Eval('')%>**

```
**HtmlCode**  
    <asp:FormView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <div >
          <%# Eval("title")  %>
    </div>
      <table>
               <tr>
                   <td> <%# Eval("S1")  %> </td>
                   <td> <%# Eval("S2")  %> </td>
                   <td> <%# Eval("S3") %> </td>
              </tr>
     </table>  


$("#btnShow").click(function () {
        var selTitle = $("#ddlEDTitle options:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{tVal:'" + selTitle + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Data Filled"); 
                },
            error: function () { alert("Error : 260"); }
        });
    });

string rawQuery = string.Empty;
        rawQuery = "SELECT Adress from temp WHERE title='" + title + "'";
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();


        ds = c.fetchData(rawQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DetailsView1.DataSource = ds;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
            ds.Clear();
        }


        rawQuery = string.Empty;
        rawQuery = "SELECT * from specification WHERE title='" + title+ "'";
        ds = c.fetchData(rawQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            //GridView1.DataMember = "specification";
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ds.Clear();
        }
```

Please guide me with your valuable knowledge.
Thanks